# iOS Bluetooth scanForPeripheralsWithServices background running works only on certain builds?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I had a working system where I was able to do peripheral scanning in the background. After refactoring my code, this functionality has stopped working.

I thought I had just missed something, but the strange thing is that the refactored version works if I run the two version of the apps (before/after refactoring) together (with different bundle id's). Does anyone know what might cause this?

Relevant Sections:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("did update central manager")
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        print("powered on central manager")
        let scanOptions = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true]

        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(nsuuid: UUID.init(uuidString: "05D27C93-F0FE-43BB-A8CB-DECFED270F8F")!)], options: scanOptions)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(RSSI)
    DataCollector.logBluetoothData(advertisementData, RSSI)
    let uuid = BluetoothModel.extractUUID(advertisementData)
    bluetoothReading[uuid] = (Date().timeIntervalSince1970, Double(truncating: RSSI))
}
```

I feel like it might have something to do with the timing between when the user grants permission to listen in the background and when it begins the listening, but I don't think this is the case based on the previous version working the way it does.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. It turns out that you can continue to monitor it, if you are also ranging for iBeacon devices.